# Sticky header CSS / JS

Tags: javascript, css

I found this website today http://www.forward-thinker.co.uk/. Does anyone know how to make a sticky header like this.?

Comment: Firefox + Firebug = find out how it works

Comment: or Internet Explorer + F12 :-P

Comment: I tried this, if I disable JS then it doesn't work. If you use firebug or chrome dev tools you can't remove the JS code without refreshing the page which puts it all back.

Comment: @DaveS, you wont be able to disable JS and have it work. For graceful degradation, just leave the header at the top of the page.

Comment: Thy shalt view source!
You know what, web development is screwed up, whatever you do, you have to publish your actual code and people can see it, try doing the view source.

Comment: @Kumar the source is obfuscated... http://pastebin.com/pACGhtem

Comment: @NickAdlwin, no source on any webapge is obfuscated if you want to read it, it can be made complex like Google does but we know, it can be read and understood :-) BTW, you already helped DaveS

Comment: it turns out that @nickAdlwin's beautifier died in between, here is the my take, clean code http://pastebin.com/Q6gncpiL

Comment: By turning JS off, I mean I know it's done using JS and not just CSS. A javascript solution is fine, and I've nearly got it working!!! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create sticky header bar for a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212624/how-to-create-sticky-header-bar-for-a-website)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That particular site utilizes jQuery's `$(window).scroll` [event](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/).  It checks if the top of the scrolled-to area (`$(this).scrollTop();`) is below a certain height.  If so, it adds to css of the header a class containing `position:fixed` (it also changes its height, since only part of the header scrolls).  If the scrolled-to area is nearer to the top, the script removes the class containing `position:fixed` from the header's css and changes the height back to its original value.

Comment: As a recommendation, I would suggest toggling a class on the header using the `scroll` event. Keep the CSS where it belongs in css files.

Comment: @zzzzBov Great suggestion!  That's actually what the site does.  Updating answer...

Comment: @NickAldwin, I'm not seeing the class change in Firebug.

Comment: @zzzzBov I see it in Chrome... The relevant part of the js can be seen here http://pastebin.com/pACGhtem (line 171)

Comment: Thanks Nick, this has helped alot!

Answer (score 3):

It's a technique called "sticky scroll" or "scroll follow"

I found some tutorials for you:

On [Nettuts](https://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/018_Floating_Menu/demo/dhtml_float_menu_final_nettut.html)

or [here](http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/scroll-follow/)

or [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/mashable-floating-effect-example-with-jquery/)

or [here](http://blog.echoenduring.com/wp-content/uploads/demos/echo_ContainedStickyScroll/)

or [here](http://www.mustafaozcan.net/en/page/jQuery-Fixed-Table-Header-Plugin.aspx)

and there's a resource here:

[Jquery Stalker](http://docs.atlassian.com/aui/3.0/jquery.stalker.js.html)