# How to keep my top menu stay fixed on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Website: http://revelationcraft.com/

In this page I want the top menu to stay on the top of the page when a user/member scrolls.

I'm wondering if this is possible if so please tell me how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `position:fixed;` to `div#ln-bar`.

Answer (score 2):

There are many questions on this such as this: [How to create sticky header bar for a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212624/how-to-create-sticky-header-bar-for-a-website)
It is called a sticky header and can be created in many different languages such as css, and jQuery. All you have to do in this case is create a `div` for your header and use this: `position:fixed;`. All you have to do is make the z-index higher than any other div or class so you don't have any troubles with this, unless of course, you want to have that happen.