# how to stop scrolling at end of the header and continue scrolling the content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Today I was watching some youtube videos when I actually noticed the website layout. I would like to know how that can be done. I would like to achieve the following website layout:

- At the end of the header, the page stops scrolling and the scrolling only has effect on the content.
- I would like to make the sidebar keep the same position and always be visible on the right side.
- I would like to point out that I don't mean a scrollbar within my content and if my explanation doesn't make sense have a look at the youtube homepage or this website http://www.squarespace.com/press-releases/.

I guess some javascript or jQuery is needed and hope you guys can give me a push in the right direction. I would really appreciate it if you guys can tell me what I'll need to use to achieve this effect.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I noticed the effect in youtube is only seen when I use the Opera browser another website with what I have in mind http://www.squarespace.com/press-releases/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sticky Header after scrolling down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382496/sticky-header-after-scrolling-down)

Comment: @user2310289 thanks for the reply but it is not the effect I had in mind.

Comment: CSS `position: fixed`? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

   var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

   //if window is scrolled past the height of the header (in my case 200px), execute code
   //or you could do this dynamically by saying scrolled > $(".header").height();
   if(scrolled > 200){ 

      $(".left").css({"position":"fixed"});

   }else{

    $(".left").css({"position":"inherit"});

   }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yLAYV/)

And FYI the page doesn't stop scrolling, the sidebar just becomes fixed to the page.

Comment: @user3188287 No problem. Glad to help. Just mark this off as correct for future use.