# Multiple sticky elements on scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I have `header` and `sidebar` div blocks and for our specific needs, I need to make both elements stick at the top once scroll event fires.

Making single element sticky is no problem but if there is more than one, it prevents scroll action and keeps jumping back to the top.

Is there any nice solution to this without using plugins?

Here is my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/N4maR/)

And, the following is the script which works well with single element.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(".sidebar").toggleClass("fixed", (fromTop > 50));
    $(".header").toggleClass("fixed", (fromTop > 50));
});
```

Comment: There is no need of JavaScript workarounds. Modern web browser can handle this event natively with CSS `position: sticky;`. Have a read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#position_sticky If you'll use the JS variation you will always have some unwanted glitches. The CSS solution is robust.

Answer (score 1):

More like this:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {

    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var elementTop = $('.anchor').offset().top;

    if(windowTop > elementTop) {
        $(".sidebar").addClass("fixed");
        $(".header").addClass("fixed");
    } else {
        $(".sidebar").removeClass("fixed");
        $(".header").removeClass("fixed");
    }

});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N4maR/2/)

Answer (score 1):

A more simple HTML/CSS-only solution would be, to add

```
position: fixed;
```

to both of the div containers right from the beginning. Thus they're always fixed no matter if the user already scrolled or not. See the solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/N4maR/3/

I don't see a special reason why it should just be fixed after a certain threshold?

Comment: Thanks. For my working setup, there is another global header apart from this header I made in the demo and we are trying to lose that global header and replace with the demo header when scrolled.

Comment: Ah, now I got the idea.

Comment: So this might be of interest for you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382496/sticky-header-after-scrolling-down

Answer (score 0):

Surprised so few answers to this.

If you have two sticky items you want to keep as separate elements, perhaps in different wrapperrs the key is to put `top: 50px` on the second sticky item (or whatever the height of the first is) so it gets 'stuck' at that position and doesn't cover the first.

There's also lots of reasons sticky can 'fail' or break. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707076/position-sticky-not-working-css-and-html) has lots of scenarios.