# Fixed header div of section at top of page when user scrolls to section

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with multiple panel divs (the red divs). I would like to make it so the red panel headers stick to the top right below the green page header as the user scrolls.

Wondering if this can be done with PURE CSS and if not that PURE JS.

Please see my current code (I would like Panel Header 2 to replace Panel Header 1 when user is scrolled to Panel Header 2, then same for Panel Header 3):

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 36px 0 0 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 60px;
}

.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}

.panel-body {
  padding-top: 27px;
}

.panel-header-fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}

.panel-header {
  background-color: red;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Fixed Scrolling Sample</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header fixed-top">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-header panel-header-fixed-top">
        <h2>Panel 1 Header</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vestibulum tortor efficitur nibh tristique, interdum
          sollicitudin sapien cursus. Vivamus ac mauris gravida, consectetur est ac, cursus odio. Aliquam lacus dui, dignissim
          sollicitudin aliquet eget, dapibus non ligula. Quisque ut rutrum felis. Integer eleifend quis turpis ac rhoncus.
          Nunc at velit in sapien tincidunt ultricies id in nibh. Curabitur tempus condimentum congue. Nam tempor dignissim
          auctor. Nulla egestas nulla velit, vel egestas leo iaculis ac. Curabitur fermentum lacinia nisi nec facilisis.
          Fusce auctor sapien id mauris interdum, sit amet aliquet libero vehicula. Etiam porttitor quis mauris non ultrices.</p>

        <p>In suscipit pulvinar pulvinar. Phasellus vitae nulla et ex blandit sollicitudin eu eu elit. Praesent fermentum
          felis nunc, ut feugiat enim luctus nec. Nulla malesuada neque at lobortis malesuada. Pellentesque consectetur libero
          odio, a commodo mi sodales tempus. Donec varius accumsan velit, semper feugiat diam maximus id. Vivamus vel leo
          a tellus pellentesque suscipit eget sit amet est.</p>

        <p>Sed hendrerit, enim ac semper dignissim, nisi turpis accumsan ante, nec porttitor libero nulla sit amet mauris.
          Nam nec malesuada erat, at hendrerit elit. Aenean eu dui viverra, euismod libero non, sodales ipsum. Suspendisse
          ut auctor nibh. Duis lobortis massa augue, et gravida ante mollis vel. Vivamus eros nibh, gravida nec tincidunt
          vel, pharetra nec felis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris velit ipsum, aliquam
          gravida convallis vel, ullamcorper in elit. Morbi porta lectus elementum lacus bibendum elementum. Ut quis nisi
          eget nunc commodo pretium. Mauris consectetur aliquam diam id gravida. Sed nec nibh est. Vestibulum et est sit
          amet ipsum posuere sodales.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vestibulum tortor efficitur nibh tristique, interdum
          sollicitudin sapien cursus. Vivamus ac mauris gravida, consectetur est ac, cursus odio. Aliquam lacus dui, dignissim
          sollicitudin aliquet eget, dapibus non ligula. Quisque ut rutrum felis. Integer eleifend quis turpis ac rhoncus.
          Nunc at velit in sapien tincidunt ultricies id in nibh. Curabitur tempus condimentum congue. Nam tempor dignissim
          auctor. Nulla egestas nulla velit, vel egestas leo iaculis ac. Curabitur fermentum lacinia nisi nec facilisis.
          Fusce auctor sapien id mauris interdum, sit amet aliquet libero vehicula. Etiam porttitor quis mauris non ultrices.</p>

        <p>In suscipit pulvinar pulvinar. Phasellus vitae nulla et ex blandit sollicitudin eu eu elit. Praesent fermentum
          felis nunc, ut feugiat enim luctus nec. Nulla malesuada neque at lobortis malesuada. Pellentesque consectetur libero
          odio, a commodo mi sodales tempus. Donec varius accumsan velit, semper feugiat diam maximus id. Vivamus vel leo
          a tellus pellentesque suscipit eget sit amet est.</p>

        <p>Proin luctus lectus libero, nec placerat turpis molestie nec. Vestibulum at velit dolor. Etiam eget consequat
          eros, ut finibus mi. Pellentesque nec mi elementum, cursus magna nec, luctus purus. Duis pretium fringilla convallis.
          Proin porta dictum leo, id euismod nunc fringilla sit amet. Fusce tellus lorem, placerat vel varius in, aliquet
          id quam. Proin tempor, sapien vitae rutrum consectetur, dui lorem convallis massa, facilisis ultricies eros neque
          sed quam. Nunc dictum et nibh commodo faucibus. Maecenas iaculis facilisis est, id malesuada quam scelerisque a.
          In finibus mauris et nibh sagittis, vitae scelerisque tellus suscipit. Donec ultricies vitae nulla at mollis. Aenean
          ullamcorper enim non dui suscipit, eu eleifend diam tincidunt. Mauris porta vitae justo eu venenatis.</p>

        <p>Suspendisse in posuere erat. Nulla porttitor, enim non interdum pellentesque, mauris urna maximus tortor, sed
          bibendum mauris dui pellentesque tellus. Praesent vehicula risus a pharetra aliquet. Sed in hendrerit erat. Sed
          aliquet libero non dui tempus euismod. Aliquam felis augue, pulvinar non ex eu, feugiat pretium dolor. In viverra
          enim lobortis lorem ultrices dictum. Proin id risus in nibh fringilla auctor vitae quis ex. Duis sodales elementum
          libero. Etiam finibus pharetra ornare. Vivamus quis sapien turpis. Sed ultricies est eget turpis pellentesque,
          vel ornare augue ornare. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse et auctor sapien.</p>

        <p>Sed hendrerit, enim ac semper dignissim, nisi turpis accumsan ante, nec porttitor libero nulla sit amet mauris.
          Nam nec malesuada erat, at hendrerit elit. Aenean eu dui viverra, euismod libero non, sodales ipsum. Suspendisse
          ut auctor nibh. Duis lobortis massa augue, et gravida ante mollis vel. Vivamus eros nibh, gravida nec tincidunt
          vel, pharetra nec felis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris velit ipsum, aliquam
          gravida convallis vel, ullamcorper in elit. Morbi porta lectus elementum lacus bibendum elementum. Ut quis nisi
          eget nunc commodo pretium. Mauris consectetur aliquam diam id gravida. Sed nec nibh est. Vestibulum et est sit
          amet ipsum posuere sodales.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-header">
        <h2>Panel 2 Header</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vestibulum tortor efficitur nibh tristique, interdum
          sollicitudin sapien cursus. Vivamus ac mauris gravida, consectetur est ac, cursus odio. Aliquam lacus dui, dignissim
          sollicitudin aliquet eget, dapibus non ligula. Quisque ut rutrum felis. Integer eleifend quis turpis ac rhoncus.
          Nunc at velit in sapien tincidunt ultricies id in nibh. Curabitur tempus condimentum congue. Nam tempor dignissim
          auctor. Nulla egestas nulla velit, vel egestas leo iaculis ac. Curabitur fermentum lacinia nisi nec facilisis.
          Fusce auctor sapien id mauris interdum, sit amet aliquet libero vehicula. Etiam porttitor quis mauris non ultrices.</p>

        <p>In suscipit pulvinar pulvinar. Phasellus vitae nulla et ex blandit sollicitudin eu eu elit. Praesent fermentum
          felis nunc, ut feugiat enim luctus nec. Nulla malesuada neque at lobortis malesuada. Pellentesque consectetur libero
          odio, a commodo mi sodales tempus. Donec varius accumsan velit, semper feugiat diam maximus id. Vivamus vel leo
          a tellus pellentesque suscipit eget sit amet est.</p>

        <p>Proin luctus lectus libero, nec placerat turpis molestie nec. Vestibulum at velit dolor. Etiam eget consequat
          eros, ut finibus mi. Pellentesque nec mi elementum, cursus magna nec, luctus purus. Duis pretium fringilla convallis.
          Proin porta dictum leo, id euismod nunc fringilla sit amet. Fusce tellus lorem, placerat vel varius in, aliquet
          id quam. Proin tempor, sapien vitae rutrum consectetur, dui lorem convallis massa, facilisis ultricies eros neque
          sed quam. Nunc dictum et nibh commodo faucibus. Maecenas iaculis facilisis est, id malesuada quam scelerisque a.
          In finibus mauris et nibh sagittis, vitae scelerisque tellus suscipit. Donec ultricies vitae nulla at mollis. Aenean
          ullamcorper enim non dui suscipit, eu eleifend diam tincidunt. Mauris porta vitae justo eu venenatis.</p>

        <p>Suspendisse in posuere erat. Nulla porttitor, enim non interdum pellentesque, mauris urna maximus tortor, sed
          bibendum mauris dui pellentesque tellus. Praesent vehicula risus a pharetra aliquet. Sed in hendrerit erat. Sed
          aliquet libero non dui tempus euismod. Aliquam felis augue, pulvinar non ex eu, feugiat pretium dolor. In viverra
          enim lobortis lorem ultrices dictum. Proin id risus in nibh fringilla auctor vitae quis ex. Duis sodales elementum
          libero. Etiam finibus pharetra ornare. Vivamus quis sapien turpis. Sed ultricies est eget turpis pellentesque,
          vel ornare augue ornare. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse et auctor sapien.</p>

        <p>Sed hendrerit, enim ac semper dignissim, nisi turpis accumsan ante, nec porttitor libero nulla sit amet mauris.
          Nam nec malesuada erat, at hendrerit elit. Aenean eu dui viverra, euismod libero non, sodales ipsum. Suspendisse
          ut auctor nibh. Duis lobortis massa augue, et gravida ante mollis vel. Vivamus eros nibh, gravida nec tincidunt
          vel, pharetra nec felis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris velit ipsum, aliquam
          gravida convallis vel, ullamcorper in elit. Morbi porta lectus elementum lacus bibendum elementum. Ut quis nisi
          eget nunc commodo pretium. Mauris consectetur aliquam diam id gravida. Sed nec nibh est. Vestibulum et est sit
          amet ipsum posuere sodales.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vestibulum tortor efficitur nibh tristique, interdum
          sollicitudin sapien cursus. Vivamus ac mauris gravida, consectetur est ac, cursus odio. Aliquam lacus dui, dignissim
          sollicitudin aliquet eget, dapibus non ligula. Quisque ut rutrum felis. Integer eleifend quis turpis ac rhoncus.
          Nunc at velit in sapien tincidunt ultricies id in nibh. Curabitur tempus condimentum congue. Nam tempor dignissim
          auctor. Nulla egestas nulla velit, vel egestas leo iaculis ac. Curabitur fermentum lacinia nisi nec facilisis.
          Fusce auctor sapien id mauris interdum, sit amet aliquet libero vehicula. Etiam porttitor quis mauris non ultrices.</p>

        <p>In suscipit pulvinar pulvinar. Phasellus vitae nulla et ex blandit sollicitudin eu eu elit. Praesent fermentum
          felis nunc, ut feugiat enim luctus nec. Nulla malesuada neque at lobortis malesuada. Pellentesque consectetur libero
          odio, a commodo mi sodales tempus. Donec varius accumsan velit, semper feugiat diam maximus id. Vivamus vel leo
          a tellus pellentesque suscipit eget sit amet est.</p>

        <p>Proin luctus lectus libero, nec placerat turpis molestie nec. Vestibulum at velit dolor. Etiam eget consequat
          eros, ut finibus mi. Pellentesque nec mi elementum, cursus magna nec, luctus purus. Duis pretium fringilla convallis.
          Proin porta dictum leo, id euismod nunc fringilla sit amet. Fusce tellus lorem, placerat vel varius in, aliquet
          id quam. Proin tempor, sapien vitae rutrum consectetur, dui lorem convallis massa, facilisis ultricies eros neque
          sed quam. Nunc dictum et nibh commodo faucibus. Maecenas iaculis facilisis est, id malesuada quam scelerisque a.
          In finibus mauris et nibh sagittis, vitae scelerisque tellus suscipit. Donec ultricies vitae nulla at mollis. Aenean
          ullamcorper enim non dui suscipit, eu eleifend diam tincidunt. Mauris porta vitae justo eu venenatis.</p>

        <p>Suspendisse in posuere erat. Nulla porttitor, enim non interdum pellentesque, mauris urna maximus tortor, sed
          bibendum mauris dui pellentesque tellus. Praesent vehicula risus a pharetra aliquet. Sed in hendrerit erat. Sed
          aliquet libero non dui tempus euismod. Aliquam felis augue, pulvinar non ex eu, feugiat pretium dolor. In viverra
          enim lobortis lorem ultrices dictum. Proin id risus in nibh fringilla auctor vitae quis ex. Duis sodales elementum
          libero. Etiam finibus pharetra ornare. Vivamus quis sapien turpis. Sed ultricies est eget turpis pellentesque,
          vel ornare augue ornare. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse et auctor sapien.</p>

        <p>Sed hendrerit, enim ac semper dignissim, nisi turpis accumsan ante, nec porttitor libero nulla sit amet mauris.
          Nam nec malesuada erat, at hendrerit elit. Aenean eu dui viverra, euismod libero non, sodales ipsum. Suspendisse
          ut auctor nibh. Duis lobortis massa augue, et gravida ante mollis vel. Vivamus eros nibh, gravida nec tincidunt
          vel, pharetra nec felis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris velit ipsum, aliquam
          gravida convallis vel, ullamcorper in elit. Morbi porta lectus elementum lacus bibendum elementum. Ut quis nisi
          eget nunc commodo pretium. Mauris consectetur aliquam diam id gravida. Sed nec nibh est. Vestibulum et est sit
          amet ipsum posuere sodales.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-header">
        <h2>Panel 3 Header</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vestibulum tortor efficitur nibh tristique, interdum
          sollicitudin sapien cursus. Vivamus ac mauris gravida, consectetur est ac, cursus odio. Aliquam lacus dui, dignissim
          sollicitudin aliquet eget, dapibus non ligula. Quisque ut rutrum felis. Integer eleifend quis turpis ac rhoncus.
          Nunc at velit in sapien tincidunt ultricies id in nibh. Curabitur tempus condimentum congue. Nam tempor dignissim
          auctor. Nulla egestas nulla velit, vel egestas leo iaculis ac. Curabitur fermentum lacinia nisi nec facilisis.
          Fusce auctor sapien id mauris interdum, sit amet aliquet libero vehicula. Etiam porttitor quis mauris non ultrices.</p>

        <p>In suscipit pulvinar pulvinar. Phasellus vitae nulla et ex blandit sollicitudin eu eu elit. Praesent fermentum
          felis nunc, ut feugiat enim luctus nec. Nulla malesuada neque at lobortis malesuada. Pellentesque consectetur libero
          odio, a commodo mi sodales tempus. Donec varius accumsan velit, semper feugiat diam maximus id. Vivamus vel leo
          a tellus pellentesque suscipit eget sit amet est.</p>

        <p>Proin luctus lectus libero, nec placerat turpis molestie nec. Vestibulum at velit dolor. Etiam eget consequat
          eros, ut finibus mi. Pellentesque nec mi elementum, cursus magna nec, luctus purus. Duis pretium fringilla convallis.
          Proin porta dictum leo, id euismod nunc fringilla sit amet. Fusce tellus lorem, placerat vel varius in, aliquet
          id quam. Proin tempor, sapien vitae rutrum consectetur, dui lorem convallis massa, facilisis ultricies eros neque
          sed quam. Nunc dictum et nibh commodo faucibus. Maecenas iaculis facilisis est, id malesuada quam scelerisque a.
          In finibus mauris et nibh sagittis, vitae scelerisque tellus suscipit. Donec ultricies vitae nulla at mollis. Aenean
          ullamcorper enim non dui suscipit, eu eleifend diam tincidunt. Mauris porta vitae justo eu venenatis.</p>

        <p>Suspendisse in posuere erat. Nulla porttitor, enim non interdum pellentesque, mauris urna maximus tortor, sed
          bibendum mauris dui pellentesque tellus. Praesent vehicula risus a pharetra aliquet. Sed in hendrerit erat. Sed
          aliquet libero non dui tempus euismod. Aliquam felis augue, pulvinar non ex eu, feugiat pretium dolor. In viverra
          enim lobortis lorem ultrices dictum. Proin id risus in nibh fringilla auctor vitae quis ex. Duis sodales elementum
          libero. Etiam finibus pharetra ornare. Vivamus quis sapien turpis. Sed ultricies est eget turpis pellentesque,
          vel ornare augue ornare. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse et auctor sapien.</p>

        <p>Sed hendrerit, enim ac semper dignissim, nisi turpis accumsan ante, nec porttitor libero nulla sit amet mauris.
          Nam nec malesuada erat, at hendrerit elit. Aenean eu dui viverra, euismod libero non, sodales ipsum. Suspendisse
          ut auctor nibh. Duis lobortis massa augue, et gravida ante mollis vel. Vivamus eros nibh, gravida nec tincidunt
          vel, pharetra nec felis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris velit ipsum, aliquam
          gravida convallis vel, ullamcorper in elit. Morbi porta lectus elementum lacus bibendum elementum. Ut quis nisi
          eget nunc commodo pretium. Mauris consectetur aliquam diam id gravida. Sed nec nibh est. Vestibulum et est sit
          amet ipsum posuere sodales.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vestibulum tortor efficitur nibh tristique, interdum
          sollicitudin sapien cursus. Vivamus ac mauris gravida, consectetur est ac, cursus odio. Aliquam lacus dui, dignissim
          sollicitudin aliquet eget, dapibus non ligula. Quisque ut rutrum felis. Integer eleifend quis turpis ac rhoncus.
          Nunc at velit in sapien tincidunt ultricies id in nibh. Curabitur tempus condimentum congue. Nam tempor dignissim
          auctor. Nulla egestas nulla velit, vel egestas leo iaculis ac. Curabitur fermentum lacinia nisi nec facilisis.
          Fusce auctor sapien id mauris interdum, sit amet aliquet libero vehicula. Etiam porttitor quis mauris non ultrices.</p>

        <p>In suscipit pulvinar pulvinar. Phasellus vitae nulla et ex blandit sollicitudin eu eu elit. Praesent fermentum
          felis nunc, ut feugiat enim luctus nec. Nulla malesuada neque at lobortis malesuada. Pellentesque consectetur libero
          odio, a commodo mi sodales tempus. Donec varius accumsan velit, semper feugiat diam maximus id. Vivamus vel leo
          a tellus pellentesque suscipit eget sit amet est.</p>

        <p>Proin luctus lectus libero, nec placerat turpis molestie nec. Vestibulum at velit dolor. Etiam eget consequat
          eros, ut finibus mi. Pellentesque nec mi elementum, cursus magna nec, luctus purus. Duis pretium fringilla convallis.
          Proin porta dictum leo, id euismod nunc fringilla sit amet. Fusce tellus lorem, placerat vel varius in, aliquet
          id quam. Proin tempor, sapien vitae rutrum consectetur, dui lorem convallis massa, facilisis ultricies eros neque
          sed quam. Nunc dictum et nibh commodo faucibus. Maecenas iaculis facilisis est, id malesuada quam scelerisque a.
          In finibus mauris et nibh sagittis, vitae scelerisque tellus suscipit. Donec ultricies vitae nulla at mollis. Aenean
          ullamcorper enim non dui suscipit, eu eleifend diam tincidunt. Mauris porta vitae justo eu venenatis.</p>

        <p>Suspendisse in posuere erat. Nulla porttitor, enim non interdum pellentesque, mauris urna maximus tortor, sed
          bibendum mauris dui pellentesque tellus. Praesent vehicula risus a pharetra aliquet. Sed in hendrerit erat. Sed
          aliquet libero non dui tempus euismod. Aliquam felis augue, pulvinar non ex eu, feugiat pretium dolor. In viverra
          enim lobortis lorem ultrices dictum. Proin id risus in nibh fringilla auctor vitae quis ex. Duis sodales elementum
          libero. Etiam finibus pharetra ornare. Vivamus quis sapien turpis. Sed ultricies est eget turpis pellentesque,
          vel ornare augue ornare. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse et auctor sapien.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vestibulum tortor efficitur nibh tristique, interdum
          sollicitudin sapien cursus. Vivamus ac mauris gravida, consectetur est ac, cursus odio. Aliquam lacus dui, dignissim
          sollicitudin aliquet eget, dapibus non ligula. Quisque ut rutrum felis. Integer eleifend quis turpis ac rhoncus.
          Nunc at velit in sapien tincidunt ultricies id in nibh. Curabitur tempus condimentum congue. Nam tempor dignissim
          auctor. Nulla egestas nulla velit, vel egestas leo iaculis ac. Curabitur fermentum lacinia nisi nec facilisis.
          Fusce auctor sapien id mauris interdum, sit amet aliquet libero vehicula. Etiam porttitor quis mauris non ultrices.</p>

        <p>In suscipit pulvinar pulvinar. Phasellus vitae nulla et ex blandit sollicitudin eu eu elit. Praesent fermentum
          felis nunc, ut feugiat enim luctus nec. Nulla malesuada neque at lobortis malesuada. Pellentesque consectetur libero
          odio, a commodo mi sodales tempus. Donec varius accumsan velit, semper feugiat diam maximus id. Vivamus vel leo
          a tellus pellentesque suscipit eget sit amet est.</p>

        <p>Suspendisse in posuere erat. Nulla porttitor, enim non interdum pellentesque, mauris urna maximus tortor, sed
          bibendum mauris dui pellentesque tellus. Praesent vehicula risus a pharetra aliquet. Sed in hendrerit erat. Sed
          aliquet libero non dui tempus euismod. Aliquam felis augue, pulvinar non ex eu, feugiat pretium dolor. In viverra
          enim lobortis lorem ultrices dictum. Proin id risus in nibh fringilla auctor vitae quis ex. Duis sodales elementum
          libero. Etiam finibus pharetra ornare. Vivamus quis sapien turpis. Sed ultricies est eget turpis pellentesque,
          vel ornare augue ornare. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse et auctor sapien.</p>

        <p>Sed hendrerit, enim ac semper dignissim, nisi turpis accumsan ante, nec porttitor libero nulla sit amet mauris.
          Nam nec malesuada erat, at hendrerit elit. Aenean eu dui viverra, euismod libero non, sodales ipsum. Suspendisse
          ut auctor nibh. Duis lobortis massa augue, et gravida ante mollis vel. Vivamus eros nibh, gravida nec tincidunt
          vel, pharetra nec felis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris velit ipsum, aliquam
          gravida convallis vel, ullamcorper in elit. Morbi porta lectus elementum lacus bibendum elementum. Ut quis nisi
          eget nunc commodo pretium. Mauris consectetur aliquam diam id gravida. Sed nec nibh est. Vestibulum et est sit
          amet ipsum posuere sodales.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-header">
        <h2>Panel 4 Header</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vestibulum tortor efficitur nibh tristique, interdum
          sollicitudin sapien cursus. Vivamus ac mauris gravida, consectetur est ac, cursus odio. Aliquam lacus dui, dignissim
          sollicitudin aliquet eget, dapibus non ligula. Quisque ut rutrum felis. Integer eleifend quis turpis ac rhoncus.
          Nunc at velit in sapien tincidunt ultricies id in nibh. Curabitur tempus condimentum congue. Nam tempor dignissim
          auctor. Nulla egestas nulla velit, vel egestas leo iaculis ac. Curabitur fermentum lacinia nisi nec facilisis.
          Fusce auctor sapien id mauris interdum, sit amet aliquet libero vehicula. Etiam porttitor quis mauris non ultrices.</p>

        <p>In suscipit pulvinar pulvinar. Phasellus vitae nulla et ex blandit sollicitudin eu eu elit. Praesent fermentum
          felis nunc, ut feugiat enim luctus nec. Nulla malesuada neque at lobortis malesuada. Pellentesque consectetur libero
          odio, a commodo mi sodales tempus. Donec varius accumsan velit, semper feugiat diam maximus id. Vivamus vel leo
          a tellus pellentesque suscipit eget sit amet est.</p>

        <p>Suspendisse in posuere erat. Nulla porttitor, enim non interdum pellentesque, mauris urna maximus tortor, sed
          bibendum mauris dui pellentesque tellus. Praesent vehicula risus a pharetra aliquet. Sed in hendrerit erat. Sed
          aliquet libero non dui tempus euismod. Aliquam felis augue, pulvinar non ex eu, feugiat pretium dolor. In viverra
          enim lobortis lorem ultrices dictum. Proin id risus in nibh fringilla auctor vitae quis ex. Duis sodales elementum
          libero. Etiam finibus pharetra ornare. Vivamus quis sapien turpis. Sed ultricies est eget turpis pellentesque,
          vel ornare augue ornare. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse et auctor sapien.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vestibulum tortor efficitur nibh tristique, interdum
          sollicitudin sapien cursus. Vivamus ac mauris gravida, consectetur est ac, cursus odio. Aliquam lacus dui, dignissim
          sollicitudin aliquet eget, dapibus non ligula. Quisque ut rutrum felis. Integer eleifend quis turpis ac rhoncus.
          Nunc at velit in sapien tincidunt ultricies id in nibh. Curabitur tempus condimentum congue. Nam tempor dignissim
          auctor. Nulla egestas nulla velit, vel egestas leo iaculis ac. Curabitur fermentum lacinia nisi nec facilisis.
          Fusce auctor sapien id mauris interdum, sit amet aliquet libero vehicula. Etiam porttitor quis mauris non ultrices.</p>

        <p>Suspendisse in posuere erat. Nulla porttitor, enim non interdum pellentesque, mauris urna maximus tortor, sed
          bibendum mauris dui pellentesque tellus. Praesent vehicula risus a pharetra aliquet. Sed in hendrerit erat. Sed
          aliquet libero non dui tempus euismod. Aliquam felis augue, pulvinar non ex eu, feugiat pretium dolor. In viverra
          enim lobortis lorem ultrices dictum. Proin id risus in nibh fringilla auctor vitae quis ex. Duis sodales elementum
          libero. Etiam finibus pharetra ornare. Vivamus quis sapien turpis. Sed ultricies est eget turpis pellentesque,
          vel ornare augue ornare. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse et auctor sapien.</p>

        <p>Sed hendrerit, enim ac semper dignissim, nisi turpis accumsan ante, nec porttitor libero nulla sit amet mauris.
          Nam nec malesuada erat, at hendrerit elit. Aenean eu dui viverra, euismod libero non, sodales ipsum. Suspendisse
          ut auctor nibh. Duis lobortis massa augue, et gravida ante mollis vel. Vivamus eros nibh, gravida nec tincidunt
          vel, pharetra nec felis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris velit ipsum, aliquam
          gravida convallis vel, ullamcorper in elit. Morbi porta lectus elementum lacus bibendum elementum. Ut quis nisi
          eget nunc commodo pretium. Mauris consectetur aliquam diam id gravida. Sed nec nibh est. Vestibulum et est sit
          amet ipsum posuere sodales.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Any code that you have tried ?

Comment: @tousif just updated post now sorry.

Comment: If so, you need javascript https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382496/sticky-header-after-scrolling-down

Comment: It will surely need some js/jquery
Demo code:-  https://codepen.io/chrissp26/pen/gBrdo

Comment: @JaeWooWoo This demo is definitely close to what I need. I will need to modify it so as the user keeps scrolling, My Header would get replaced with the header of whatever section they are on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this could help you only css, let me know if is useful for you.

```css
.wrapper {
          padding: 36px 0 0 0;
        }
    
        .header {
          background-color: green;
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          height: 60px;
        }
    
        .fixed-top {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          right: 0;
          left: 0;
          z-index: 1030;
        }
    
        .panel-body {
          padding-top: 27px;
        }
    
        .panel-header-fixed-top {
          position: fixed;
          top: 60;
          right: 0;
          left: 0;
         /* z-index: 1030;*/
        }
    
        .panel-header {
            background-color: red;
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            position: sticky;
            top: 60px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    
        h1 {
          margin: 0;
        }
    
        h2 {
          margin: 0;
        }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Fixed Scrolling Sample</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header fixed-top">
          <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
          <div class="panel-header panel-header-fixed-top">
            <h2>Panel 1 Header</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vestibulum tortor efficitur nibh tristique, interdum
              sollicitudin sapien cursus. Vivamus ac mauris gravida, consectetur est ac, cursus odio. Aliquam lacus dui, dignissim
              sollicitudin aliquet eget, dapibus non ligula. Quisque ut rutrum felis. Integer eleifend quis turpis ac rhoncus.
              Nunc at velit in sapien tincidunt ultricies id in nibh. Curabitur tempus condimentum congue. Nam tempor dignissim
              auctor. Nulla egestas nulla velit, vel egestas leo iaculis ac. Curabitur fermentum lacinia nisi nec facilisis.
              Fusce auctor sapien id mauris interdum, sit amet aliquet libero vehicula. Etiam porttitor quis mauris non ultrices.</p>

            <p>In suscipit pulvinar pulvinar. Phasellus vitae nulla et ex blandit sollicitudin eu eu elit. Praesent fermentum
              felis nunc, ut feugiat enim luctus nec. Nulla malesuada neque at lobortis malesuada. Pellentesque consectetur libero
              odio, a commodo mi sodales tempus. Donec varius accumsan velit, semper feugiat diam maximus id. Vivamus vel leo
              a tellus pellentesque suscipit eget sit amet est.</p>

            <p>Sed hendrerit, enim ac semper dignissim, nisi turpis accumsan ante, nec porttitor libero nulla sit amet mauris.
              Nam nec malesuada erat, at hendrerit elit. Aenean eu dui viverra, euismod libero non, sodales ipsum. Suspendisse
              ut auctor nibh. Duis lobortis massa augue, et gravida ante mollis vel. Vivamus eros nibh, gravida nec tincidunt
              vel, pharetra nec felis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris velit ipsum, aliquam
              gravida convallis vel, ullamcorper in elit. Morbi porta lectus elementum lacus bibendum elementum. Ut quis nisi
              eget nunc commodo pretium. Mauris consectetur aliquam diam id gravida. Sed nec nibh est. Vestibulum et est sit
              amet ipsum posuere sodales.
            </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vestibulum tortor efficitur nibh tristique, interdum
              sollicitudin sapien cursus. Vivamus ac mauris gravida, consectetur est ac, cursus odio. Aliquam lacus dui, dignissim
              sollicitudin aliquet eget, dapibus non ligula. Quisque ut rutrum felis. Integer eleifend quis turpis ac rhoncus.
              Nunc at velit in sapien tincidunt ultricies id in nibh. Curabitur tempus condimentum congue. Nam tempor dignissim
              auctor. Nulla egestas nulla velit, vel egestas leo iaculis ac. Curabitur fermentum lacinia nisi nec facilisis.
              Fusce auctor sapien id mauris interdum, sit amet aliquet libero vehicula. Etiam porttitor quis mauris non ultrices.</p>

            <p>In suscipit pulvinar pulvinar. Phasellus vitae nulla et ex blandit sollicitudin eu eu elit. Praesent fermentum
              felis nunc, ut feugiat enim luctus nec. Nulla malesuada neque at lobortis malesuada. Pellentesque consectetur libero
              odio, a commodo mi sodales tempus. Donec varius accumsan velit, semper feugiat diam maximus id. Vivamus vel leo
              a tellus pellentesque suscipit eget sit amet est.</p>

            <p>Proin luctus lectus libero, nec placerat turpis molestie nec. Vestibulum at velit dolor. Etiam eget consequat
              eros, ut finibus mi. Pellentesque nec mi elementum, cursus magna nec, luctus purus. Duis pretium fringilla convallis.
              Proin porta dictum leo, id euismod nunc fringilla sit amet. Fusce tellus lorem, placerat vel varius in, aliquet
              id quam. Proin tempor, sapien vitae rutrum consectetur, dui lorem convallis massa, facilisis ultricies eros neque
              sed quam. Nunc dictum et nibh commodo faucibus. Maecenas iaculis facilisis est, id malesuada quam scelerisque a.
              In finibus mauris et nibh sagittis, vitae scelerisque tellus suscipit. Donec ultricies vitae nulla at mollis. Aenean
              ullamcorper enim non dui suscipit, eu eleifend diam tincidunt. Mauris porta vitae justo eu venenatis.</p>

            <p>Suspendisse in posuere erat. Nulla porttitor, enim non interdum pellentesque, mauris urna maximus tortor, sed
              bibendum mauris dui pellentesque tellus. Praesent vehicula risus a pharetra aliquet. Sed in hendrerit erat. Sed
              aliquet libero non dui tempus euismod. Aliquam felis augue, pulvinar non ex eu, feugiat pretium dolor. In viverra
              enim lobortis lorem ultrices dictum. Proin id risus in nibh fringilla auctor vitae quis ex. Duis sodales elementum
              libero. Etiam finibus pharetra ornare. Vivamus quis sapien turpis. Sed ultricies est eget turpis pellentesque,
              vel ornare augue ornare. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse et auctor sapien.</p>

            <p>Sed hendrerit, enim ac semper dignissim, nisi turpis accumsan ante, nec porttitor libero nulla sit amet mauris.
              Nam nec malesuada erat, at hendrerit elit. Aenean eu dui viverra, euismod libero non, sodales ipsum. Suspendisse
              ut auctor nibh. Duis lobortis massa augue, et gravida ante mollis vel. Vivamus eros nibh, gravida nec tincidunt
              vel, pharetra nec felis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris velit ipsum, aliquam
              gravida convallis vel, ullamcorper in elit. Morbi porta lectus elementum lacus bibendum elementum. Ut quis nisi
              eget nunc commodo pretium. Mauris consectetur aliquam diam id gravida. Sed nec nibh est. Vestibulum et est sit
              amet ipsum posuere sodales.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
          <div class="panel-header">
            <h2>Panel 2 Header</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vestibulum tortor efficitur nibh tristique, interdum
              sollicitudin sapien cursus. Vivamus ac mauris gravida, consectetur est ac, cursus odio. Aliquam lacus dui, dignissim
              sollicitudin aliquet eget, dapibus non ligula. Quisque ut rutrum felis. Integer eleifend quis turpis ac rhoncus.
              Nunc at velit in sapien tincidunt ultricies id in nibh. Curabitur tempus condimentum congue. Nam tempor dignissim
              auctor. Nulla egestas nulla velit, vel egestas leo iaculis ac. Curabitur fermentum lacinia nisi nec facilisis.
              Fusce auctor sapien id mauris interdum, sit amet aliquet libero vehicula. Etiam porttitor quis mauris non ultrices.</p>

            <p>In suscipit pulvinar pulvinar. Phasellus vitae nulla et ex blandit sollicitudin eu eu elit. Praesent fermentum
              felis nunc, ut feugiat enim luctus nec. Nulla malesuada neque at lobortis malesuada. Pellentesque consectetur libero
              odio, a commodo mi sodales tempus. Donec varius accumsan velit, semper feugiat diam maximus id. Vivamus vel leo
              a tellus pellentesque suscipit eget sit amet est.</p>

            <p>Proin luctus lectus libero, nec placerat turpis molestie nec. Vestibulum at velit dolor. Etiam eget consequat
              eros, ut finibus mi. Pellentesque nec mi elementum, cursus magna nec, luctus purus. Duis pretium fringilla convallis.
              Proin porta dictum leo, id euismod nunc fringilla sit amet. Fusce tellus lorem, placerat vel varius in, aliquet
              id quam. Proin tempor, sapien vitae rutrum consectetur, dui lorem convallis massa, facilisis ultricies eros neque
              sed quam. Nunc dictum et nibh commodo faucibus. Maecenas iaculis facilisis est, id malesuada quam scelerisque a.
              In finibus mauris et nibh sagittis, vitae scelerisque tellus suscipit. Donec ultricies vitae nulla at mollis. Aenean
              ullamcorper enim non dui suscipit, eu eleifend diam tincidunt. Mauris porta vitae justo eu venenatis.</p>

            <p>Suspendisse in posuere erat. Nulla porttitor, enim non interdum pellentesque, mauris urna maximus tortor, sed
              bibendum mauris dui pellentesque tellus. Praesent vehicula risus a pharetra aliquet. Sed in hendrerit erat. Sed
              aliquet libero non dui tempus euismod. Aliquam felis augue, pulvinar non ex eu, feugiat pretium dolor. In viverra
              enim lobortis lorem ultrices dictum. Proin id risus in nibh fringilla auctor vitae quis ex. Duis sodales elementum
              libero. Etiam finibus pharetra ornare. Vivamus quis sapien turpis. Sed ultricies est eget turpis pellentesque,
              vel ornare augue ornare. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse et auctor sapien.</p>

            <p>Sed hendrerit, enim ac semper dignissim, nisi turpis accumsan ante, nec porttitor libero nulla sit amet mauris.
              Nam nec malesuada erat, at hendrerit elit. Aenean eu dui viverra, euismod libero non, sodales ipsum. Suspendisse
              ut auctor nibh. Duis lobortis massa augue, et gravida ante mollis vel. Vivamus eros nibh, gravida nec tincidunt
              vel, pharetra nec felis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris velit ipsum, aliquam
              gravida convallis vel, ullamcorper in elit. Morbi porta lectus elementum lacus bibendum elementum. Ut quis nisi
              eget nunc commodo pretium. Mauris consectetur aliquam diam id gravida. Sed nec nibh est. Vestibulum et est sit
              amet ipsum posuere sodales.
            </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vestibulum tortor efficitur nibh tristique, interdum
              sollicitudin sapien cursus. Vivamus ac mauris gravida, consectetur est ac, cursus odio. Aliquam lacus dui, dignissim
              sollicitudin aliquet eget, dapibus non ligula. Quisque ut rutrum felis. Integer eleifend quis turpis ac rhoncus.
              Nunc at velit in sapien tincidunt ultricies id in nibh. Curabitur tempus condimentum congue. Nam tempor dignissim
              auctor. Nulla egestas nulla velit, vel egestas leo iaculis ac. Curabitur fermentum lacinia nisi nec facilisis.
              Fusce auctor sapien id mauris interdum, sit amet aliquet libero vehicula. Etiam porttitor quis mauris non ultrices.</p>

            <p>In suscipit pulvinar pulvinar. Phasellus vitae nulla et ex blandit sollicitudin eu eu elit. Praesent fermentum
              felis nunc, ut feugiat enim luctus nec. Nulla malesuada neque at lobortis malesuada. Pellentesque consectetur libero
              odio, a commodo mi sodales tempus. Donec varius accumsan velit, semper feugiat diam maximus id. Vivamus vel leo
              a tellus pellentesque suscipit eget sit amet est.</p>

            <p>Proin luctus lectus libero, nec placerat turpis molestie nec. Vestibulum at velit dolor. Etiam eget consequat
              eros, ut finibus mi. Pellentesque nec mi elementum, cursus magna nec, luctus purus. Duis pretium fringilla convallis.
              Proin porta dictum leo, id euismod nunc fringilla sit amet. Fusce tellus lorem, placerat vel varius in, aliquet
              id quam. Proin tempor, sapien vitae rutrum consectetur, dui lorem convallis massa, facilisis ultricies eros neque
              sed quam. Nunc dictum et nibh commodo faucibus. Maecenas iaculis facilisis est, id malesuada quam scelerisque a.
              In finibus mauris et nibh sagittis, vitae scelerisque tellus suscipit. Donec ultricies vitae nulla at mollis. Aenean
              ullamcorper enim non dui suscipit, eu eleifend diam tincidunt. Mauris porta vitae justo eu venenatis.</p>

            <p>Suspendisse in posuere erat. Nulla porttitor, enim non interdum pellentesque, mauris urna maximus tortor, sed
              bibendum mauris dui pellentesque tellus. Praesent vehicula risus a pharetra aliquet. Sed in hendrerit erat. Sed
              aliquet libero non dui tempus euismod. Aliquam felis augue, pulvinar non ex eu, feugiat pretium dolor. In viverra
              enim lobortis lorem ultrices dictum. Proin id risus in nibh fringilla auctor vitae quis ex. Duis sodales elementum
              libero. Etiam finibus pharetra ornare. Vivamus quis sapien turpis. Sed ultricies est eget turpis pellentesque,
              vel ornare augue ornare. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse et auctor sapien.</p>

            <p>Sed hendrerit, enim ac semper dignissim, nisi turpis accumsan ante, nec porttitor libero nulla sit amet mauris.
              Nam nec malesuada erat, at hendrerit elit. Aenean eu dui viverra, euismod libero non, sodales ipsum. Suspendisse
              ut auctor nibh. Duis lobortis massa augue, et gravida ante mollis vel. Vivamus eros nibh, gravida nec tincidunt
              vel, pharetra nec felis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris velit ipsum, aliquam
              gravida convallis vel, ullamcorper in elit. Morbi porta lectus elementum lacus bibendum elementum. Ut quis nisi
              eget nunc commodo pretium. Mauris consectetur aliquam diam id gravida. Sed nec nibh est. Vestibulum et est sit
              amet ipsum posuere sodales.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
          <div class="panel-header">
            <h2>Panel 3 Header</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vestibulum tortor efficitur nibh tristique, interdum
              sollicitudin sapien cursus. Vivamus ac mauris gravida, consectetur est ac, cursus odio. Aliquam lacus dui, dignissim
              sollicitudin aliquet eget, dapibus non ligula. Quisque ut rutrum felis. Integer eleifend quis turpis ac rhoncus.
              Nunc at velit in sapien tincidunt ultricies id in nibh. Curabitur tempus condimentum congue. Nam tempor dignissim
              auctor. Nulla egestas nulla velit, vel egestas leo iaculis ac. Curabitur fermentum lacinia nisi nec facilisis.
              Fusce auctor sapien id mauris interdum, sit amet aliquet libero vehicula. Etiam porttitor quis mauris non ultrices.</p>

            <p>In suscipit pulvinar pulvinar. Phasellus vitae nulla et ex blandit sollicitudin eu eu elit. Praesent fermentum
              felis nunc, ut feugiat enim luctus nec. Nulla malesuada neque at lobortis malesuada. Pellentesque consectetur libero
              odio, a commodo mi sodales tempus. Donec varius accumsan velit, semper feugiat diam maximus id. Vivamus vel leo
              a tellus pellentesque suscipit eget sit amet est.</p>

            <p>Proin luctus lectus libero, nec placerat turpis molestie nec. Vestibulum at velit dolor. Etiam eget consequat
              eros, ut finibus mi. Pellentesque nec mi elementum, cursus magna nec, luctus purus. Duis pretium fringilla convallis.
              Proin porta dictum leo, id euismod nunc fringilla sit amet. Fusce tellus lorem, placerat vel varius in, aliquet
              id quam. Proin tempor, sapien vitae rutrum consectetur, dui lorem convallis massa, facilisis ultricies eros neque
              sed quam. Nunc dictum et nibh commodo faucibus. Maecenas iaculis facilisis est, id malesuada quam scelerisque a.
              In finibus mauris et nibh sagittis, vitae scelerisque tellus suscipit. Donec ultricies vitae nulla at mollis. Aenean
              ullamcorper enim non dui suscipit, eu eleifend diam tincidunt. Mauris porta vitae justo eu venenatis.</p>

            <p>Suspendisse in posuere erat. Nulla porttitor, enim non interdum pellentesque, mauris urna maximus tortor, sed
              bibendum mauris dui pellentesque tellus. Praesent vehicula risus a pharetra aliquet. Sed in hendrerit erat. Sed
              aliquet libero non dui tempus euismod. Aliquam felis augue, pulvinar non ex eu, feugiat pretium dolor. In viverra
              enim lobortis lorem ultrices dictum. Proin id risus in nibh fringilla auctor vitae quis ex. Duis sodales elementum
              libero. Etiam finibus pharetra ornare. Vivamus quis sapien turpis. Sed ultricies est eget turpis pellentesque,
              vel ornare augue ornare. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse et auctor sapien.</p>

            <p>Sed hendrerit, enim ac semper dignissim, nisi turpis accumsan ante, nec porttitor libero nulla sit amet mauris.
              Nam nec malesuada erat, at hendrerit elit. Aenean eu dui viverra, euismod libero non, sodales ipsum. Suspendisse
              ut auctor nibh. Duis lobortis massa augue, et gravida ante mollis vel. Vivamus eros nibh, gravida nec tincidunt
              vel, pharetra nec felis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris velit ipsum, aliquam
              gravida convallis vel, ullamcorper in elit. Morbi porta lectus elementum lacus bibendum elementum. Ut quis nisi
              eget nunc commodo pretium. Mauris consectetur aliquam diam id gravida. Sed nec nibh est. Vestibulum et est sit
              amet ipsum posuere sodales.
            </p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vestibulum tortor efficitur nibh tristique, interdum
              sollicitudin sapien cursus. Vivamus ac mauris gravida, consectetur est ac, cursus odio. Aliquam lacus dui, dignissim
              sollicitudin aliquet eget, dapibus non ligula. Quisque ut rutrum felis. Integer eleifend quis turpis ac rhoncus.
              Nunc at velit in sapien tincidunt ultricies id in nibh. Curabitur tempus condimentum congue. Nam tempor dignissim
              auctor. Nulla egestas nulla velit, vel egestas leo iaculis ac. Curabitur fermentum lacinia nisi nec facilisis.
              Fusce auctor sapien id mauris interdum, sit amet aliquet libero vehicula. Etiam porttitor quis mauris non ultrices.</p>

            <p>In suscipit pulvinar pulvinar. Phasellus vitae nulla et ex blandit sollicitudin eu eu elit. Praesent fermentum
              felis nunc, ut feugiat enim luctus nec. Nulla malesuada neque at lobortis malesuada. Pellentesque consectetur libero
              odio, a commodo mi sodales tempus. Donec varius accumsan velit, semper feugiat diam maximus id. Vivamus vel leo
              a tellus pellentesque suscipit eget sit amet est.</p>

            <p>Proin luctus lectus libero, nec placerat turpis molestie nec. Vestibulum at velit dolor. Etiam eget consequat
              eros, ut finibus mi. Pellentesque nec mi elementum, cursus magna nec, luctus purus. Duis pretium fringilla convallis.
              Proin porta dictum leo, id euismod nunc fringilla sit amet. Fusce tellus lorem, placerat vel varius in, aliquet
              id quam. Proin tempor, sapien vitae rutrum consectetur, dui lorem convallis massa, facilisis ultricies eros neque
              sed quam. Nunc dictum et nibh commodo faucibus. Maecenas iaculis facilisis est, id malesuada quam scelerisque a.
              In finibus mauris et nibh sagittis, vitae scelerisque tellus suscipit. Donec ultricies vitae nulla at mollis. Aenean
              ullamcorper enim non dui suscipit, eu eleifend diam tincidunt. Mauris porta vitae justo eu venenatis.</p>

            <p>Suspendisse in posuere erat. Nulla porttitor, enim non interdum pellentesque, mauris urna maximus tortor, sed
              bibendum mauris dui pellentesque tellus. Praesent vehicula risus a pharetra aliquet. Sed in hendrerit erat. Sed
              aliquet libero non dui tempus euismod. Aliquam felis augue, pulvinar non ex eu, feugiat pretium dolor. In viverra
              enim lobortis lorem ultrices dictum. Proin id risus in nibh fringilla auctor vitae quis ex. Duis sodales elementum
              libero. Etiam finibus pharetra ornare. Vivamus quis sapien turpis. Sed ultricies est eget turpis pellentesque,
              vel ornare augue ornare. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse et auctor sapien.</p>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vestibulum tortor efficitur nibh tristique, interdum
              sollicitudin sapien cursus. Vivamus ac mauris gravida, consectetur est ac, cursus odio. Aliquam lacus dui, dignissim
              sollicitudin aliquet eget, dapibus non ligula. Quisque ut rutrum felis. Integer eleifend quis turpis ac rhoncus.
              Nunc at velit in sapien tincidunt ultricies id in nibh. Curabitur tempus condimentum congue. Nam tempor dignissim
              auctor. Nulla egestas nulla velit, vel egestas leo iaculis ac. Curabitur fermentum lacinia nisi nec facilisis.
              Fusce auctor sapien id mauris interdum, sit amet aliquet libero vehicula. Etiam porttitor quis mauris non ultrices.</p>

            <p>In suscipit pulvinar pulvinar. Phasellus vitae nulla et ex blandit sollicitudin eu eu elit. Praesent fermentum
              felis nunc, ut feugiat enim luctus nec. Nulla malesuada neque at lobortis malesuada. Pellentesque consectetur libero
              odio, a commodo mi sodales tempus. Donec varius accumsan velit, semper feugiat diam maximus id. Vivamus vel leo
              a tellus pellentesque suscipit eget sit amet est.</p>

            <p>Suspendisse in posuere erat. Nulla porttitor, enim non interdum pellentesque, mauris urna maximus tortor, sed
              bibendum mauris dui pellentesque tellus. Praesent vehicula risus a pharetra aliquet. Sed in hendrerit erat. Sed
              aliquet libero non dui tempus euismod. Aliquam felis augue, pulvinar non ex eu, feugiat pretium dolor. In viverra
              enim lobortis lorem ultrices dictum. Proin id risus in nibh fringilla auctor vitae quis ex. Duis sodales elementum
              libero. Etiam finibus pharetra ornare. Vivamus quis sapien turpis. Sed ultricies est eget turpis pellentesque,
              vel ornare augue ornare. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse et auctor sapien.</p>

            <p>Sed hendrerit, enim ac semper dignissim, nisi turpis accumsan ante, nec porttitor libero nulla sit amet mauris.
              Nam nec malesuada erat, at hendrerit elit. Aenean eu dui viverra, euismod libero non, sodales ipsum. Suspendisse
              ut auctor nibh. Duis lobortis massa augue, et gravida ante mollis vel. Vivamus eros nibh, gravida nec tincidunt
              vel, pharetra nec felis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris velit ipsum, aliquam
              gravida convallis vel, ullamcorper in elit. Morbi porta lectus elementum lacus bibendum elementum. Ut quis nisi
              eget nunc commodo pretium. Mauris consectetur aliquam diam id gravida. Sed nec nibh est. Vestibulum et est sit
              amet ipsum posuere sodales.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
          <div class="panel-header">
            <h2>Panel 4 Header</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris vestibulum tortor efficitur nibh tristique, interdum
              sollicitudin sapien cursus. Vivamus ac mauris gravida, consectetur est ac, cursus odio. Aliquam lacus dui, dignissim
              sollicitudin aliquet eget, dapibus non ligula. Quisque ut rutrum felis. Integer eleifend quis turpis ac rhoncus.
              Nunc at velit in sapien tincidunt ultricies id in nibh. Curabitur tempus condimentum congue. Nam tempor dignissim
              auctor. Nulla egestas nulla velit, vel egestas leo iaculis ac. Curabitur fermentum lacinia nisi nec facilisis.
              Fusce auctor sapien id mauris interdum, sit amet aliquet libero vehicula. Etiam porttitor quis mauris non ultrices.</p>

            <p>In suscipit pulvinar pulvinar. Phasellus vitae nulla et ex blandit sollicitudin eu eu elit. Praesent fermentum
              felis nunc, ut feugiat enim luctus nec. Nulla malesuada neque at lobortis malesuada. Pellentesque consectetur libero
              odio, a commodo mi sodales tempus. Donec varius accumsan velit, semper feugiat diam maximus id. Vivamus vel leo
              a tellus pellentesque suscipit eget sit amet est.</p>

            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you David, looks like it is exactly what I want besides the part where you see the header being replaced slowly slide off the screen. Also, I am unable to figure out what the main changes you made from my original are to get this working.

Comment: @BlakeRivell please check again my answer and  uncomment this line in the class `   .fixed-top {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          right: 0;
          left: 0;
          z-index: 1030;
        }`. the z-index