# How to make header Fixed while horizontal and vertical scrolling

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to set the header of , (not for div header) from React-bootstrap while using making it vertically and horizontally scrollable.

I have tried to make it work by using `display: block` but it's messing up table in responsive mode.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="padding-top-16" id="maximise" >
        {this.renderActionItems()}
        <div className={'col-xs-12'} style={{ marginTop: '16px', marginBottom: '16px' }}>
          <Table hover responsive>
            <thead>
              {this.renderHeaders()}
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.renderRows()}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

.table-responsive {
  max-height: 550px;
  border: 1px solid var(--colorInputBorder);
  color: var(--colorDarkPrimary);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.table-responsive td,
.table-responsive th {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 8px 20px !important;
}
```

This is what i have done to make the table vertically and horizontally scrollable and it's working fine but the header is not fixed.

NOTE: As i have used react-bootstrap the class named `responsive` adds extra `<div>` outside of `<Table>` with class name `table-responsive`

**I DO NOT WANT TO MAKE IT WORK BY SETTING WIDTH MANUALLY**

Comment: Try this : **[HTML Table with Fixed Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers)**

Comment: If you are using a pre-build react-table component, then they should be having options for fixed headed tables. Otherwise, you could just go for a regular table header fix, which works irrespective of bootstrap or ReactJS inclusions

Comment: Yes @VarunNair, I have checked it but React-bootstrap does not provide such facility. It's already using bootstrap 3 as a base.

Comment: @DharaVihol, then you could try a simple fixed/ sticky header fix. Refer to the posts mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it but while i use display: block it becomes messy as i have mentioned in question. @VarunNair

Comment: I think it's different @iLuvLogix. I am looking for a solution for table header..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382496/sticky-header-after-scrolling-down
So, this may not work..

Comment: You don't have to change the '*display*' property of the table. Try working with the '***position***' property for the header. Go through those posts. You'll find the solution there.

Comment: Cool! Thanks @VarunNair. I will try and let you know if it works..