# How do you stop your website from reacting to cropping

Tags: browser, responsive-design

on   http://starwars.ea.com/starwars/battlefront/news/supremacy-mode-all-out-galactic-conquest    when you crop the page up it doesnt react and move all of your content! How do you do that?

here is what I tried:

```
.nav { 
    display:block; 
    min-width:100%; 
    text-align: left; 
    position:fixed; 
    top:0; left:0; 
    list-style-type:none; 
    z-index:1000; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #3c8dbc 0%, #307196 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #3c8dbc 0%, #307196 100%);
    color:#A3A3A3; 
    height:10%; 
    font-weight:lighter; 
    overflow:hidden; 
} 

.nav li { 
    display: inline-block; 
    margin:1%; 
    height:3%; 
    list-style-type:none; 
    color:#A3A3A3; 
} 
.nav ul{ 
    list-style-type:none;
} 
.nav ul li{ 
    list-style-type:none; color:white; 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean when you scoll down ? the upper side is a sticky bar.

Comment: Similar question has been asked before, Please do research before you ask. Check this out anyway :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212624/how-to-create-sticky-header-bar-for-a-website

Comment: can you write the code for how i would apply that to this code i have been trying to get it to work and it doesnt!

Comment: .nav {
 display:block;
 min-width:100%;
 text-align: left;
    position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 list-style-type:none;
 z-index:1000;
 margin:0 auto;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #3c8dbc 0%, #307196 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #3c8dbc 0%, #307196 100%);
    color:#A3A3A3;
 height:10%;
 font-weight:lighter;
   overflow:hidden;
   
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:1%;
 height:3%;
    list-style-type:none;
 color:#A3A3A3;
}


.nav ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}


.nav ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
 color:white;
}

Comment: Tried to explain in the below example hope it helps.